# Ground rod in an area surrounded by trees

Tags: grounding

I have some questions about ground rod installation.

- If a small part of the rod is kept outside the soil, wouldn't be that a low resistance point where a lightning can choose to go?
- Does it need to be covered with something to increase its resistance to the outside or there always must be a lightning rod nearby with a slower resistance?

I'm asking because I'll put the rod in a remote place surrounded by trees, so a lightning over there would be a sure fire. Also not sure where to put a lightning rod in a place like that.

Comment: Why would you expect lightning to strike the inch or so of rod poking out of the ground rather than any one of the surrounding trees standing many feet above ground?

Comment: @brhans because I don't know what resistance do trees have. So are the trees more able to receive the lightning than the rod?

Comment: Resistance only becomes a factor once the current starts flowing, so the initial breakdown is going to follow the easiest (highest) path.. In any case, trees are typically full of water with lots of dissolved ions, so they're relatively conductive (at least compared to dry ground).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If a small part of the rod is kept outside the soil, wouldn't be that a low resistance point where a lightning can choose to go?

If the ground rod were out in the middle of a field where it's the tallest thing around, then yeah, probably. If the ground rod were surrounded by trees, I would expect lightning to always hit the trees, not the rod. After all, if the rod is next to a living 20 foot tree, then the rod has 20 feet of air above it that the tree does not have, and it's much easier for the lightning to go through 20 feet of live tree than 20 feet of air.

> Does it need to be covered with something to increase its resistance to the outside or there always must be a lightning rod nearby with a slower resistance?

I can't think of any reason why you would need either of those things. What's the hazard that you're worried about?

> I'm asking because I'll put the rod in a remote place surrounded by trees, so a lightning over there would be a sure fire.

It's true that if a tree gets struck by lightning, that may cause a fire. What does that have to do with a ground rod? Are you concerned that the ground rod may somehow increase the chance that a tree would get struck by lightning? As far as I know, a ground rod would have no effect at all on the lightning risk.

Answer (score 2):

1. What is the *purpose* of the ground rod? Low-frequency antenna ground? Lightning protection for an antenna? Lightning protection for AC mains entrance? For an electric fences? usw.
2. What is the soil like? Some soils are conductive, others need treatment for an effective ground, or burying a ground plane.
3. What are the electrical codes in your locale? Some allow use of a buried metallic water pipe, others cite definite rules, such as having an inspection pit.
   See online guides for directions, such [Axis-India](https://axis-india.com/installing-ground-rod-explained/), and [Tameson](https://tameson.com/pages/ground-rod).

Comment: I was told to put a ground rod for a completely off-grid small installation. It will provide the earthing required by devices such a generator and an inverter. Don't know the soil characteristics in advance and I'll don't know much the local code.. just the maximum ground resistance that I'll need to meet. If the place wasn't that remote I would hire an electrician. Thanks but those guides don't answer my questions